# Is it possible to query for dns Alias of Server in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server with an alias.

- example server name "USIADBT02"
- example alias name "sql_test"

I want to know if there is a SQL query I can run that can tell me the server alias name based off of the current connection. Meaning, regardless of whether a connection is made using the actual server name or the alias, I want my query to return the alias name "sql test"

Not sure if this is possible but hoped someone could tell me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add an sp_ in master to return the desired value as a string... .. .. :)

Answer (score 3):

No, the DNS alias is not a property that the SQL Server itself stores , and cannot be obtained by any SQL query (unless you store it in a table yourself).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I appreciate the confirmation